# How to check if record does NOT exist in Rails 5 with active record querying?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an article model and comments model. How do i get a list of articles that does not have any comments using active record?

Model Columns:

Article: `body:string` (has many comments)

Comment: `body:string`, `article_id:integer` (belongs to article)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the result using single query and want the result to be an activerecord relation, use:

```
Article.where('id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(article_id) FROM comments)')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is same but would be more rails way

```
Article.where.not('id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(article_id) FROM comments)')
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code to fetch all articles with no comments:

```
Article.includes(:comments).where.not(comments: {article_id: nil})
```

OR

```
data = []

Article.all.each do |a|
  data << a if a.comments.blank?
end

puts data
```

OR

```
ids = Comment.all.pluck(:article_id)

data = Article.where.not(id: ids)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.